# Conditioned based string matching using grepl and ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, string-matching, grepl

I have a dataframe df, mentioned below.

```
a <- c(1:6)
b <- c("Audi,BMW,Skoda, Rackets,Toy,Football",
       "Suzuki,Kawasaki,Ducati,Aprilia,Baseball, Rugby",
       "Mazda, Ford, chevrolet,Mercedes,Gloves,Helmet",
       "Lemon,Yamaha,Table,Kawasaki,Chair,Fruits", 
       "Ford, chevrolet,Bread,Ducati,Tesla,Hyundai",
       "Honey,Apple,Alcohol,cake,Sweets, Mango")
       df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

*

I also have two list containing brand name of cars and bikes.

```
cars <- c("Audi","BMW","Ford","Skoda","Mazda","chevrolet","Mercedes","Volkswagen","Tesla","Hyundai","Lamborghini","Mini-Cooper","Lexus")
motorbike <- c("Yamaha","Suzuki","Kawasaki","Harley-Davidson","Ducati","Aprilia","KTM", "Triumph","Piaggio","Hyosung","Vespa","MV-Agusta")
```

I used grepl with ifelse to match the words from the two list in df$b and assign a value to each rows if they have a match.

```
df$c<-ifelse(grepl(paste(cars, collapse="|"), df$b), "cars",
      ifelse(grepl(paste(motorbike, collapse="|"),df$b), "bikes","others"))
```

Now, I want to put a condition that if 4 or more than 4 words are matching in each row, only then a value (car,bike) is assigned in df$c. I want my df to be like this:

```
structure(list(a = 1:6, b = structure(c(1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("Audi,BMW,Skoda, Rackets,Toy,Football", "Ford, chevrolet,Bread,Ducati,Tesla,Hyundai", 
"Honey,Apple,Alcohol,cake,Sweets, Mango", "Lemon,Yamaha,Table,Kawasaki,Chair,Fruits", 
"Mazda, Ford, chevrolet,Mercedes,Gloves,Helmet", "Suzuki,Kawasaki,Ducati,Aprilia,Baseball, Rugby"
), class = "factor"), c = c("others", "bikes", "cars", "others", 
"cars", "others")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? Of course you can delete the amountcars and amountmotors columns. And do you expect it will never occur you have both >3 cars and >3 motors in a string? Based on comment, I have now updated my answer.

```
library(stringr)
df$amountcars <- str_count(df$b, paste(cars, collapse="|"))
df$amountmotors <- str_count(df$b, paste(motorbike, collapse="|"))



df$c <- ifelse(df$amountcars > 3 & df$amountcars > df$amountmotors, "cars", ifelse(df$amountmotors > 3 & df$amountmotors > df$amountcars, "bikes", "others"))
df

  a                                              b amountcars amountmotors      c
1 1           Audi,BMW,Skoda, Rackets,Toy,Football          3            0 others
2 2 Suzuki,Kawasaki,Ducati,Aprilia,Baseball, Rugby          0            4  bikes
3 3  Mazda, Ford, chevrolet,Mercedes,Gloves,Helmet          4            0   cars
4 4       Lemon,Yamaha,Table,Kawasaki,Chair,Fruits          0            2 others
5 5     Ford, chevrolet,Bread,Ducati,Tesla,Hyundai          4            1   cars
6 6         Honey,Apple,Alcohol,cake,Sweets, Mango          0            0 others
```

Based on comments if you have like 9 strings:
First create all vectors with strings:

```
cars <- c("Audi","BMW","Ford","Skoda","Mazda","chevrolet","Mercedes","Volkswagen","Tesla","Hyundai","Lamborghini","Mini-Cooper","Lexus")
motorbike <- c("Yamaha","Suzuki","Kawasaki","Harley-Davidson","Ducati","Aprilia","KTM", "Triumph","Piaggio","Hyosung","Vespa","MV-Agusta")
```

Then put these in a list, and add the names

```
list1 <- list(cars, motorbike)
names(list1) <- c("cars", "motorbike")
```

Finally, run this code:

```
df$d <- 
ifelse(apply(sapply(list1, function(x) str_count(df$b, paste0(x, collapse = "|"))), 1, max) > 3,
apply(sapply(list1, function(x) str_count(df$b, paste0(x, collapse = "|"))), 1, function(x) names(list1)[which.max(x)]),
"others")
```

Basically, it calculates the max number of strings from one of the vectors, and if it is above 3, it assigns the appropriate name, otherwise it assigns "others".

Comment: Your Approach is partially correct. What if the df$b has 20 words. amountcars has 7 words and amountmotors has 13 words, in this case it will assign a value 'car' which is wrong. I want that the row with the greater count value between amountcars and amountmotors should be assigned with Car or bike.

Comment: That's why I asked what you would like to happen in that case, I have now updated my answer. :)

Comment: Actually I have 9 columns to count (str_count) and then I need to assign the value to the greatest among them. Sorry for not mentioning this in previous comment. Is there any solution to just look at the column with the maximum count and assign the value to it?

Comment: I figure it out, I have to use multiple  & conditions. I have a very big dataframe and I think that these Operators will increase the runtime. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just a found a way without needing to create all those columns.. Let me update my answer

Comment: Update is Perfect. :-D